# Controlling width of container when child changes size

Tags: javascript, width

I have an inline block containing many figures.
Each figure contains one image of varying sizes all shown at 90% and one caption.
Each figure has mouseenter and mouseleave function.
On mouseenter I change the height of the image from 90% to 80% (and reverse on mouseleave)

This creates an unpleasant flicker when the figure's width changes and can set up a persistent flicker as the mouse continally enters and leaves the moving figure(s).

Can I control width of the figure?  (Figure.width doesn't want to play)

There is a click event which hides all but this figure and zooms this one; that works OK.

Complete program below including click event.

I tried to capture and rest the width of the figure after changing the height of the image but can't get that to work.
My attempt is visible in the code at lines 85 et seq.

```
<head>

<style>
figure {
    display: inline-block;
}

figure.awfigure {
  height: 190px;
  margin:0px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color:green;
}
figcaption::after{
    content: attr(after);
    font-size:75%;
    color: rgb(3, 68, 130);
    float: right;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
img.awthumb {
  height: 90%;
  margin:0px;
  }


#container1 {
    text-align: center;
}


</style>



<body>
    
    <h1>This row is a &ltdiv</h1>
   <div id="container1">
        <figure class="awfigure">
            <img  src="https://www.rotary-ribi.org/upimages/PageMainPics/Raffle_Tickets.jpg" alt="Latest Update." class="awthumb" />
            <figcaption align="center"></figcaption>
        </figure>
        <figure class="awfigure">
            <img  src="https://www.rotary-ribi.org/upimages/clubpics/BobM.jpg" alt="Latest Update. - President Bob McKenzie" class="awthumb" />
            <figcaption align="center"></figcaption>
        </figure>
        <figure class="awfigure">
            <img  src="https://www.rotary-ribi.org/upimages/clubpics/DSC_4723_edited-2.jpg" alt="Irene Stuart has joined the Orkney Club after many years of work in the Community supporting charities." class="awthumb" />
            <figcaption align="center"></figcaption>
        </figure>
        <figure class="awfigure">
            <img  src="https://www.rotary-ribi.org/upimages/clubpics/Golf16.jpg" alt="Ally Bruce wins the annual golf competition, seen here receiving the award from last years winner Ronnie Johnson." class="awthumb" />
            <figcaption align="center"></figcaption>
        </figure>
    </figure><figure class="awfigure">
        <img  src="https://www.rotary-ribi.org/upimages/clubpics/Coffee_Morning_Stromness.jpg" alt="Latest Update. - Stromness Coffee Event" class="awthumb" />
        <figcaption align="center"></figcaption>
    </figure>
</figure><figure class="awfigure">
    <img  src="https://www.rotary-ribi.org/upimages/clubpics/Coffee_Morning_Stromness.jpg" alt="Latest Update. - Stromness Coffee Event" class="awthumb" />
    <figcaption align="center"></figcaption>
</figure>
</div>
           
<script>
/* set up mouse enter, leave anf click on each figure*/
let figures = document.querySelectorAll( '.awfigure' );
for ( var i = 0; i < figures.length; i = i + 1 )
    {
        let thisfig = figures[ i ];
        thisfig.parentElement.popped = false; /*no figurse currently clicked*/
        
        thisfig.addEventListener( "mouseenter", function ()
        {
            
            if ( ! this.parentElement.popped )
            {
                captions = this.getElementsByTagName( 'FIGCAPTION' );
                captions[ 0 ].innerHTML = "";/*there is only one caption*/
                captions[ 0 ].setAttribute( 'after', "  - Click to Open.  " );
                this.style.borderColor = "red";
                thumbs = this.getElementsByTagName( 'IMG' );

/*Attempting to save and recover the figure's width - doesn't work
/* capture width of figure before change height of image*/
               let x=this.width;

/*Change height of image in this figure*/
                thumbs[0].style.height = "80%"; /*there is only one img*/

/* restore width of figure after changing height of image */
               this.style.width=x;
            }
        } )

        thisfig.addEventListener( "mouseleave", function ()
        {
            if ( ! this.parentElement.popped )
            {
                captions = this.getElementsByTagName( 'FIGCAPTION' );
                captions[ 0 ].innerHTML = "";
                captions[ 0 ].setAttribute( 'after', "" );
                thumbs = this.getElementsByTagName( 'IMG' );
                thisthumb=thumbs[0];
                thisthumb.style.height = "90%";
                this.style.borderColor = "green";
                this.style.height = "190px";
            }
        } )
        thisfig.addEventListener( "click", function ()
        {
            var thumbs = this.getElementsByTagName( 'IMG' );
            var thisthumb=thumbs[0];
            captions = this.getElementsByTagName( 'FIGCAPTION' );
            var thiscaption=captions[0];
            if ( this.parentElement.popped )
            {
                awhidesibs( 'awfigure', 'inline-block' ,'awfigure');
                this.style.height = "190px";
                thisthumb.style.height = "90%";
                thiscaption.innerHTML = "";
                thiscaption.setAttribute( 'after', "  - Click to Open.  " );
                this.parentElement.popped = false;
            }
            else
            {
                awhidesibs( 'awfigure', 'none' ,'awfigure');
                this.style.display="inline-block";
                this.style.height = "400px";
                thisthumb.style.height = "90%";
                thiscaption.innerHTML = thisthumb.alt;
                thiscaption.setAttribute( 'after', "  - Click to Close.  " );
                this.parentElement.popped = true;
            }
        } )


    }

    function awhidesibs( x, y,z ) /*when figure clicked hide all other figures*/
    {
    var siblings = document.getElementsByClassName(x);
    for ( var i = 0; i < siblings.length; i = i + 1 )
    {
        btn = siblings[ i ];
        if( btn.className.includes(x))
        {btn.style.display = y;}
        }
    }    
</script>
```

Comment: Answer 1 (thanks) is neat but ignores the need for the user to be able to click on the figure to see a larger version. I had omitted this from the code for brevity but the full code is above.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, i think i understand your issue

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>CSS3 Image Transform Gallery</title>
<style>
    ul {
        margin: 50px;
        list-style: none;
    }
    ul li {
        margin: 10px;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    ul li a {
        padding: 5px;
        display: inline-block;      
        border: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
    }
    ul li a img {
        width: 125px;
        height: 125px;
        display: block;
    }
    ul li a:hover img {
        transform: scale(0.9);
        box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><img  src="https://www.rotary-ribi.org/upimages/PageMainPics/Raffle_Tickets.jpg" alt="Latest Update." class="awthumb" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img  src="https://www.rotary-ribi.org/upimages/clubpics/DSC_4723_edited-2.jpg" alt="Irene Stuart has joined the Orkney Club after many years of work in the Community supporting charities." class="awthumb" />
            </a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img  src="https://www.rotary-ribi.org/upimages/clubpics/Golf16.jpg" alt="Ally Bruce wins the annual golf competition, seen here receiving the award from last years winner Ronnie Johnson." class="awthumb" />
            </a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img  src="https://www.rotary-ribi.org/upimages/clubpics/Coffee_Morning_Stromness.jpg" alt="Latest Update. - Stromness Coffee Event" class="awthumb" />
        </a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img  src="https://www.rotary-ribi.org/upimages/clubpics/Coffee_Morning_Stromness.jpg" alt="Latest Update. - Stromness Coffee Event" class="awthumb" />
        </a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img  src="https://www.rotary-ribi.org/upimages/clubpics/Coffee_Morning_Stromness.jpg" alt="Latest Update. - Stromness Coffee Event" class="awthumb" />
    
        </a></li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks - Nice but how about the 'Click to Open' - please see my more complete code above.

Comment: what are you trying to do in click event?

Comment: hide all the other figures and show this figure a bit bigger. This works in my code not a problem - try it?